# Kolla-Toolbox container doesnt deploy on a fresh Openstack install

Tags: openstack, kolla-ansible

I'm trying to do a fresh install of Openstack on a 3 physical servers (running Ubuntu 22.04) using Kolla Ansible.

One controller + 2 compute nodes with an "already deployed" Ceph backend.

After successful bootstrap and precheck commands - the deploy fails with the below error. What am I doing wrong please?

**Error:**

```
RUNNING HANDLER [common : Initializing toolbox container using normal user] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [compute1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": ["docker", "exec", "-t", "kolla_toolbox", "ansible", "--version"], "delta": "0:00:00.024701", "end": "2023-09-30 04:01:25.073781", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2023-09-30 04:01:25.049080", "stderr": "Error response from daemon: Container 99a51a579864fe3ef7488b1b4dc17a56592e83daa6c0b8b613558b7fa220147f is not running", "stderr_lines": ["Error response from daemon: Container 99a51a579864fe3ef7488b1b4dc17a56592e83daa6c0b8b613558b7fa220147f is not running"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
fatal: [compute2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": ["docker", "exec", "-t", "kolla_toolbox", "ansible", "--version"], "delta": "0:00:00.025507", "end": "2023-09-30 04:01:25.068792", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2023-09-30 04:01:25.043285", "stderr": "Error response from daemon: Container 6906e087c3dd4d31f34d3195cb5d7a0864787f983a4e57f8853bd8207765e35f is not running", "stderr_lines": ["Error response from daemon: Container 6906e087c3dd4d31f34d3195cb5d7a0864787f983a4e57f8853bd8207765e35f is not running"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
fatal: [controller]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": ["docker", "exec", "-t", "kolla_toolbox", "ansible", "--version"], "delta": "0:00:00.251685", "end": "2023-09-30 04:01:25.338619", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2023-09-30 04:01:25.086934", "stderr": "Error response from daemon: Container e29c6b8e1f2b05a0c834779e871cf543e37b4d3015a8af26dd71fe8299ac0eb3 is not running", "stderr_lines": ["Error response from daemon: Container e29c6b8e1f2b05a0c834779e871cf543e37b4d3015a8af26dd71fe8299ac0eb3 is not running"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

**My "Globals.yml" file:**

```
(kolla-ansible-venv01) root@controller:~# grep -v '^\s*$\|^\s*\#' /etc/kolla/globals.yml
---
workaround_ansible_issue_8743: yes
kolla_base_distro: "ubuntu"
openstack_release: "zed"
kolla_internal_vip_address: "192.168.2.21"
kolla_external_vip_address: "192.168.2.22"
network_interface: "en10"
neutron_external_interface: "en01"
neutron_plugin_agent: "openvswitch"
enable_openstack_core: "yes"
enable_haproxy: "yes"
enable_keepalived: "{{ enable_haproxy | bool }}"
enable_cinder: "yes"
enable_cinder_backup: "yes"
enable_cinder_backend_iscsi: "yes"
enable_openvswitch: "{{ enable_neutron | bool and neutron_plugin_agent != 'linuxbridge' }}"
ceph_glance_user: "glance"
ceph_glance_keyring: "ceph.client.glance.keyring"
ceph_glance_pool_name: "images"
ceph_cinder_user: "client.admin"
ceph_cinder_keyring: "ceph.client.cinder.keyring"
ceph_cinder_pool_name: "volumes"
ceph_cinder_backup_user: "client.admin"
ceph_cinder_backup_keyring: "ceph.client.cinder-backup.keyring"
ceph_cinder_backup_pool_name: "backups"
ceph_nova_keyring: "ceph.client.nova.keyring"
ceph_nova_user: "nova"
ceph_nova_pool_name: "vms"
glance_backend_ceph: "yes"
glance_backend_file: "yes"
nova_backend_ceph: "yes"
nova_compute_virt_type: "kvm"
nova_console: "novnc"
```

**Attachments:**

Log file which has the output of the "kolla-ansible deploy -vvvv" command:
https://paste.ee/p/1mQra